# Multilevel model with 4 levels?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model

My dataset is a pretty typical educational dataset: we have data about students, courses, faculty, schools, and I plan to include partially-crossed random effects because students could enroll in multiple courses from the same faculty member or in courses from multiple faculty members.

I have predictors at all levels except for school (school n = 22). Is a four-level model ideal? Or should I run a three-level model and include the school data as fixed dummy variables?

My understanding is that I can't use lme4 for four-level models--so if I should be modeling the data with four levels, what are packages that might help me do so?

Comment: Why do you think lme4 cannot fit a 4-level model ?

Comment: I've heard that from people with much more lme4 experience than me, but are we wrong?

Comment: Yes, I believe so

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no restriction to the number of "levels" in `lme4`. The package will be able to fit any number of levels provided that the data supports such a random effects structure.

We can demonstrate with the following simulation of a 4-level dataset similar to that as described in the OP:

```
> set.seed(15)
> library(lme4)
> dt1 <- data.frame(expand.grid(SchoolID = LETTERS[1:6], FacultyID = LETTERS[1:6], CourseID = LETTERS[1:10], StudentID = 1:100, Score = c(NA, NA, NA)))
> dt1$Score <- as.numeric(dt1$SchoolID) + as.numeric(dt1$FacultyID) + as.numeric(dt1$CourseID) + as.numeric(dt1$StudentID) + rnorm(nrow(dt1), 0,5)
> lmm1 <- lmer(Score ~ 1 + (1 | SchoolID/FacultyID/CourseID/StudentID), data = dt1)
> summary(lmm1)  
Random effects:
 Groups                                    Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 StudentID:(CourseID:(FacultyID:SchoolID)) (Intercept) 841.6574 29.0113 
 CourseID:(FacultyID:SchoolID)             (Intercept)   0.8581  0.9263 
 FacultyID:SchoolID                        (Intercept)   2.5579  1.5993 
 SchoolID                                  (Intercept)   2.8880  1.6994 
 Residual                                               24.9743  4.9974 
Number of obs: 108000, groups:  
StudentID:(CourseID:(FacultyID:SchoolID)), 36000; CourseID:(FacultyID:SchoolID), 360; FacultyID:SchoolID, 36; SchoolID, 6
```

We could also fit a 5-level model if we wished:

```
> dt2 <- data.frame(expand.grid(CityID = LETTERS[1:6], SchoolID = LETTERS[1:6], FacultyID = LETTERS[1:6], CourseID = LETTERS[1:10], StudentID = 1:20, Score = c(NA, NA, NA)))
> dt2$Score <- as.numeric(dt2$CityID) + as.numeric(dt2$SchoolID) + as.numeric(dt2$FacultyID) + as.numeric(dt2$CourseID) + as.numeric(dt2$StudentID) + rnorm(nrow(dt2), 0, 5)
> lmm2 <- lmer(Score ~ 1 + (1 | CityID/SchoolID/FacultyID/CourseID/StudentID), data = dt2)
> summary(lmm2)  
Random effects:
 Groups                                             Name        Variance 
Std.Dev.
 StudentID:(CourseID:(FacultyID:(SchoolID:CityID))) (Intercept) 34.778   5.897   
 CourseID:(FacultyID:(SchoolID:CityID))             (Intercept)  7.418   2.724   
 FacultyID:(SchoolID:CityID)                        (Intercept)  2.516   1.586   
 SchoolID:CityID                                    (Intercept)  2.873   1.695   
 CityID                                             (Intercept)  2.922   1.709   
 Residual                                                       24.940   4.994   
Number of obs: 129600, groups:  
StudentID:(CourseID:(FacultyID:(SchoolID:CityID))), 43200; CourseID:(FacultyID:(SchoolID:CityID)), 2160; FacultyID:(SchoolID:CityID), 216; SchoolID:CityID, 36; CityID, 6
```

[ Note that this 2nd model may take a while to fit ! ]

The partially crossed structure would be best represented by ensuring that the factors in each clusters are coded uniquely and `lme4` should then be able to handle the partially crossed / partially nested structure simply by specifying the random effects as

```
(1 | SchoolID) + (1 | FacultyID) + (1 | CourseID) + (1 | StudentID)
```

This means that, for example, if you have  `StudentID 1` in `Faculty A` and `Student 1` in `Faculty B` and these are **different** (ie, these 2 students are nested in their respective Faculties), then they should be coded as something like `StudentID 1A`  and `StudentID 1B` respectively. We can demonstrate this with the `dt1` dataset above, by re-coding the factors as follows:

```
> dt1.1 <- dt1
> dt1.1$FacultyID <- paste(dt1$SchoolID, dt1$FacultyID, sep = ".")
> dt1.1$CourseID <- paste(dt1.1$FacultyID, dt1$CourseID, sep = ".")
> dt1.1$StudentID <- paste(dt1.1$CourseID, dt1$StudentID, sep = ".")
> lmm1.1 <- lmer(Score ~ 1 + (1 | SchoolID) + (1 | FacultyID) + (1 | CourseID) + (1 | StudentID), data = dt1.1)
> summary(lmm1.1)  

Random effects:
 Groups    Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 StudentID (Intercept) 841.6568 29.0113 
 CourseID  (Intercept)   0.8584  0.9265 
 FacultyID (Intercept)   2.5585  1.5995 
 SchoolID  (Intercept)   2.8893  1.6998 
 Residual               24.9743  4.9974 
Number of obs: 108000, groups:  StudentID, 36000; CourseID, 360; FacultyID, 36; SchoolID, 6
```

Note that the model output is the same as for `lmm1` above, although presented slightly differently.

So far the data are fully nested. That is, each student is enrolled on 1 and only 1 course, one course "belongs" to one and only 1 Faculty etc. To simulate a crossed factor, for example a student that is enrolled on 2 courses, we can simply combine the relevant student IDs: First we identify the student IDs that we want to combine:

```
> dt1.1[dt1.1$StudentID == "A.A.A.31" | dt1.1$StudentID == "A.A.B.31", ]
      SchoolID FacultyID CourseID StudentID    Score
10801        A       A.A    A.A.A  A.A.A.31 33.00600
10837        A       A.A    A.A.B  A.A.B.31 33.69633
46801        A       A.A    A.A.A  A.A.A.31 33.03089
46837        A       A.A    A.A.B  A.A.B.31 33.00802
82801        A       A.A    A.A.A  A.A.A.31 41.68804
82837        A       A.A    A.A.B  A.A.B.31 31.26155
```

and gives them the same (unique) ID:

```
> dt1.1[dt1.1$StudentID == "A.A.A.31" | dt1.1$StudentID == "A.A.B.31", ]$StudentID   <- "CCCC"
```

And then we can fit the model with the same same call:

```
lmm1.1 <- lmer(Score ~ 1 + (1 | SchoolID) + (1 | FacultyID) + (1 | CourseID) + (1 | StudentID), data = dt1.1)
> summary(lmm1.1)  
Random effects:
 Groups    Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 StudentID (Intercept) 841.6867 29.0118 
 CourseID  (Intercept)   0.8312  0.9117 
 FacultyID (Intercept)   2.5570  1.5991 
 SchoolID  (Intercept)   2.8851  1.6986 
 Residual               24.9742  4.9974 
Number of obs: 108000, groups:  StudentID, 35999; CourseID, 360; FacultyID, 36; SchoolID, 6
```

Note that we now have 35,999 `StudentID`s, rather than 36,000.

See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228800/crossed-vs-nested-random-effects-how-do-they-differ-and-how-are-they-specified/228814#228814) for more info about coding crossed and nested factors.